# PhpStorm 7 align consecutive combined operators and assignments

Tags: php, phpstorm

Code style of php in PhpStorm v7 can align consecutive assignments. But is there a way to make it align the combined operators as well?

Example:

```
$a = 1;
$a *= 2;
$foo = 2;
```

Should become:

```
$a   = 1;
$a  *= 2;
$foo = 2;
```

Comment: I found this by applying the "Default" Scheme, then is about copying it and creating your own.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin you can install via the browse repositories button on the plugins part of the settings window called Front End Alignment.

Once it's installed you will have a command called Regex Align under the Code drop down.  I don't know much about it except that you can highlight the code you want to align and execute this command.  It will bring up a window and I just entered an equals sign and hit OK and it will align your code based on the farthest equals sign.

I'm new to PHPStorm and I just found this plugin so I'm sure it does more but that should at least get you started.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sounds promising, I will try that.

Comment: Unfortunately that splits the `+` and `=` from each other. `$b +  = 3;`

Comment: Sorry, like I said I just started using it.  It says it will accept regex so maybe that's the answer but I don't know regex that well.  You could maybe ask the guy that wrote it: Jon Mulieri https://github.com/jmulieri/front-end-alignment

Answer (score 0):

Almost all PHP-coding standards such as Zend and PSR (http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/coding-standard.html) disfavor such alignment, because  when you working in team every other member have to do this useless beautifying, even if they don't have it preset with PHPStorm.

Comment: This is does not answer the OP's question. This should be a comment under the question.

Comment: Actually my company set this standard and PhpStorm is destroying it, every time I reformat.